# PIVOT y JOIN IN sql

Tags: sql, pivot-table

hope someone can help me, please.

`SELECT id.id, ticket.ticket FROM tabla.id JOIN tabla.ticket ON id.sym = ticket.sym`

The result I have is the following:

```
| id | ticket | 
| -- | ------ | 
| 1  |   A1   | 
| 1  |   A2   |
| 1  |   A3   |
| 2  |   E1   |
| 2  |   E2   |
| 2  |   E3   | 
| .  |    .   | 
| .  |    .   | 
| n  |    n   |
```

The result shows me that for a single ID there can be many different tickets associated with the same ID, what I need is to obtain something horizontal, since this table comes from a join, and I will add more columns with other joins. I hope to get something like this..

```
|    id    | Column B | Col c | Col D | Col N |
|    1     |    A1    |   A2  |  A3   |  A4   | 
|    2     |    B1    |   B2  |  B3   |  NULL | 
|    N     |    N     |
```

Comment: First, what RDBMS are you using (MS Sql server, mysql, oracle, postgres, snowflake, etc)? Please update the tags in your question with the appropriate platform. Second, and this is true for any RDBMS, creating a pivot that has, as it's output, a dynamic number of columns, is going to be difficult or impossible without some non-sql scripting. This is best done outside of SQL (like in an excel pivot or a pandas dataframe).

Comment: Just add a row numbering for each id group  and alias each  row number as a column after pivot https://dbfiddle.uk/u1BCK7G9

Answer (score 0):

If your RDBMS is MS SQL Server, I suggest adding row numbering for each id group. You can then alias each row number as a columns B,C,D,E,... after the pivot

```
--Create example table
CREATE TABLE [tablaPlusId] 
(
    [id]    VARCHAR(512),
    [ticket]    VARCHAR(512)
);

--insert into example table
INSERT INTO [tablaPlusId] ([id], [ticket]) VALUES
    ('1', 'A1'),
    ('1', 'A2'),
    ('1', 'A3'),
    ('1', 'A4'),  
    ('2', 'E1'),
    ('2', 'E2'),
    ('2', 'E3');

--Add row numbering within each id group
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ASC) AS rn  
INTO #temp
FROM tablaPlusId

Print 'Validate the numbering of items within an id group'  
Select * from #temp

Print 'Pivot on Ticket then alias each row number column as B,C,D,...'  
SELECT ID, [1] as [Column B], [2] as [Column C], [3] as [Column D], [4] as [Column E]
FROM  #temp
PIVOT 
(
  MIN(ticket)  
  FOR rn IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])  
) AS PivotTable;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1NUVdUPr)

| ID | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 |
| 2 | E1 | E2 | E3 | null |

Comment: Why a temp table, what does that gain you over a derived subquery?

Comment: @Charlieface because I am lazy and https://tableconvert.com/csv-to-sql makes the construct and insert commands for me automatically.  Also, temp tables can have improved performance and less locking issues. I also like the option of updating the records in steps if necessary.

Comment: @Charlieface I use temp tables for StackOverflow examples because they allow me to show the records at each step for education purposes.